# Do bodybuilders lose their sex drive when they are dyhadrated and extremely low in body fat for competition?

Tags: bodybuilding

Even though their bodies literally exude maximised sex appeal thus bodybuilders naturally convey this idea of strong sex drive or horniness I heard a fit guy say that bodybuilders only look like the ultimate epitome of male sex energy, but in reality they lose their sex drive due to being so dehydrated and being so low in body fat when they compete.

Is that right? Do dehydration and low body fat make bodybuilders' sex drive go away?

The competitions always have a bit of sexual charge for obvious reasons (nothing wrong with that) so it surprised me to hear how that extreme preparation may deprive them of what they seem to project in abundance.

Comment: Being dehydrated and starving would pretty much remove any thoughts other than food and water.

Comment: Just fasted for 7 days in a row to lose 5 kilograms, yeah 0 sex drive but muscle mass is pretty much the same.

Answer (score 4):

Basic answer is yes. Testosterone and other hormones use and require fat to be made, stored, and/or processed by the body. So when body fat drops and fats from diet hit extremely low levels the body can't make or store the hormones like normal.

Dehydration can cause all sorts of issues depending on severity. Even being 2% dehydrated(the smallest amount measurable as of 2010) can cause a slight decrease in athletic performance.

Comment: Talking from experience, this is true.  When you're down near 5%ish BF then you become a little "floppy and limp" for lack of better words.